# how to show desktop icons in 21.10 desktop?

Tags: desktop-environments, .desktop, 21.04, desktop-icons, 21.10

how can I show all icons in my desktop. after upgrading to 21.10 all icons in desktop is disappeared.
even Tweaks can't help at that.

your help is appreciated

thank you

Comment: Can you edit your question and include more details about what you mean?  I cannot reproduce this problem on a live session of Ubuntu Desktop 21.10 (GNOME).  The contents of `~/Desktop` are shown as icons on the desktop.

Comment: I mean, before the update, my desktop has more than 20 folders. after updating to kernel 21.10 all folders in desktop disappeared. maybe that related to gnome or something else. however, how can I make all my folders appear again in desktop?

Comment: I use gnome 40.4 and kernel 5.13 and window system wayland

Comment: Are those folders still located under `~/Desktop`?

Comment: I click on files icon in Dock, then go to desktop, I can see them all

Comment: I am having the same problem with 21.10 and nemo as default explorer instead of nautilus.  No Desktop Icons and no way to fix it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My desktop icons disappeared when I upgraded to Ubuntu 21.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1369508/my-desktop-icons-disappeared-when-i-upgraded-to-ubuntu-21-10)

Comment: unfortunately didn't work

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was copy `/usr/share/applications/nemo-autostart.desktop` towards `~/.config/autostart/nemo-autostart.desktop` and in that file remove the line `OnlyShowIn=X-Cinnamon`

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Nemo#Desktop_icons_not_shown

So one need some way to copy. This can be in Linux using the terminal program `cp`: Open up a terminal program.

Copy/Type in: `cp /usr/share/applications/nemo-autostart.desktop ~/.config/autostart/nemo-autostart.desktop`
This copies the nemo-autostart desktop file towards your personal autostart files. This is because `~` in the shell is by many shells replaced to your personal home directory. This is generally something like `/home/yourname`. Then you can open the file with an editor. You can open an editor by clicking the icon, and selecting the path, or typing in the name of the editor may work as well. For example `gedit ~/.config/autostart/nemo-autostart.desktop` will open the file in gedit. `mousepad`, etc works generally the same. Now *.desktop* files are just text files that represent an application for the end user. Every line specifies something about the application. Remove the line containing `OnlyShowIn=X-Cinnamon`. Then save the file. Log out. Log in and enjoy the desktop icons working.

You may need to do this action for every user.

Maybe one can even just edit the `/usr/share/applications/nemo-autostart.desktop` file itself (this requires administrator privileges). Tell me if this works. An update *may* break desktop icons then, however.

Comment: could you explain how to do that? please. as I'm very beginner

Comment: Okay I will, I had trouble with this problem myself, so you just need some way to copy and some way to edit

Comment: Honestly I found this post when searching for a solution