# My desktop icons disappeared when I upgraded to Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: gnome-shell, desktop-icons, 21.10

After upgrading my machine from Ubuntu 21.04 to 21.10, the desktop has no icons. Even the default Trash and Home icons are not visible. How can I bring back the icons?

`env | grep XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` outputs:

```
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME
```

Comment: Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/, or use the `Extensions` app, to re-enable the `desktop-icons` or `desktop-icons NG` (DING) gnome shell extensions.

Comment: Extensions shows nothing named `desktop-icons`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu 21.10 uses a different gnome shell extension to provide icons on the desktop, "Desktop Icons NG" rather than "Desktop Icons".

That the upgrade process did not correctly replace the package `gnome-shell-extensions-desktop-icons` with the new `gnome-shell-extensions-desktop-icons-ng` is related to your specific configuration *and* the fact that the old extension is not anymore packaged in Ubuntu 21.10.

With "your specific configuration", I suspect that following customization from your part some standard metapackages (eg. `ubuntu-desktop`) may not anymore be on your system. In that case, the new package is not pulled in together with the updated metapackage. However, the old package is removed because it does not anymore exist in the new version. If you do have the metapackage, however, then this is to be considered a bug in the upgrader.

The solution is to manually install the new package:

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng
```

You may need to activate the extension using the Extensions tool. Install it with

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-prefs
```

Start the tool searching for "Extensions".

Answer (score 0):

Icons disappeared for me as well,from the dock and desktop.
My fix was to restore the desktop back to default by going into home folder. Then ctrl+h to show hidden files, then navigate to config/dconf. Once your there rename dconf to dconf.bak.

Restart your machine and you should be greeted with a stock Ubuntu desktop. You will lose all your favorite positions and some settings that you will have to re-enable but that should bring it all back to a working state.

Comment: My dock icons are fine, But the icons which were meant to be in desktop is not there.

Comment: Did you try the fix I posted, it will reset your desktop back to default and bring back your standard desktop icons. You can also reset them by running this command from the terminal. dconf reset -f /

Comment: No, It just reset dock, theme, wallpaper, icon size on dock etc. but not showing desktop icons.

Comment: Maybe try to reinstall the desktop-icons extension. sudo apt reinstall gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng

Comment: Reinstalling the `gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng` fixed my issue.

Comment: That's great then it must have removed it somehow on the update.

Answer (score 0):

Found a [Similiar post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1372269/1360702) here with the same symptoms ( like mine :/ )

I've upgraded from 21.04 to 21.10 and afterwards my desktop is just the blank background image!
The Files are still there and if I start with vanilla gnome session I can also see them.

I have already tried installing DING from https://extensions.gnome.org/, with apt, also purging... I've revisited all my sources and they are all fine! (and the most up-to-date!
Nothing helping so far.
Is there any way I can re-trigger the upgrade process as if I was still running 21.04? I DO have a backup but I wouldn't want to go back to it as I've taken it from a live system with dd...

Comment: Well this is not an answer , This type of things should be first posted in comment box :) Welcome to ask ubuntu

Comment: sorry, can't yet post to comments! trying my best!